# bidirectional relationship returning empty set on OneToMany and works only on ManyToOne

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i have 2 entities, Category and Feature, each Category has one or many features.

when creating a category along with its features, fetching the new category returns an empty set on the features attribute.

```java
    @PostMapping("/sub")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_admin')")
    public HttpEntity<CategoryDTO> createSubCategory(@Valid @RequestBody CreateCategory createCategory)
    {
        Category category = categoryService.create(createCategory,mainCategoryService.one(createCategory.getMainCategory_id()));
        featureService.bulkCreate(createCategory.getFeatures(),category);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(modelMapper.map(category,CategoryDTO.class));
    }
```

this is the data that i'm sending:

`{"name":"SUB","mainCategory_id":1,"features":{"F1":"SLIDER","F2":"CHECKBOX"}}`

and this is the data returned by the controller:

`{"id":2,"name":"SUB","mainCategory":{"id":1,"name":"CATEGORY"},"features":[]}`

as you can see, the features are empty.

This is the test to create a category with its features:

```java
    @Test
    public void testIfAdminCanCreateSubCategory_expect201AndMainCategoryIdEqualsTheAssociatedOne() throws Exception {
        String category = "{\"name\" : \"CATEGORY\"}";
        String sub = "{\"name\":\"SUB\",\"mainCategory_id\":1,\"features\":{\"F1\":\"SLIDER\",\"F2\":\"CHECKBOX\"}}";
        mockMvc().with(keycloakAuthenticationToken().authorities("ROLE_admin")).perform(post("/categories").content(category).contentType("application/json"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andDo(r -> mockMvc().with(keycloakAuthenticationToken().authorities("ROLE_admin"))
                        .post(sub,"/categories/sub")
                        .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.mainCategory.id").value(1))
                        .andDo(print())
                       // .andExpect(jsonPath("$.features[0]").value("SLIDER"))
                );
        //featureService.all().forEach( f -> System.out.println(f.getCategory().getId()));
    }
```

when decommenting the last line, it prints the category id ( which is 2 as shown in the returned data ), meaning that the ManyToOne is working, but not the OneToMany.

My models:

```java
@Entity
@EntityListeners( AuditingEntityListener.class  )
@Data
public class Category {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) private Long id;
    ....
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "category" , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    Set<Feature> features = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Feature {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private Long id;
    private String name;
    private FeatureType type;
    @ManyToOne Category category;
}
```

the create method in categoryService:

```java
    @Override
    public Category create(CreateCategory createCategory, MainCategory mainCategory) {
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setName(createCategory.getName().toUpperCase());
        category.setMainCategory(mainCategory);
        return categoryRepository.save(category);
    }
```

the bulkCreate method in the featureService:

```java
    @Override
    public Feature create(String feature, FeatureType type, Category category) {
        Feature f = new Feature();
        f.setName(feature);
        f.setType(type);
        f.setCategory(category);
        return featureRepository.save(f);
    }

    @Override
    public void bulkCreate(Map<String, FeatureType> features, Category category) {
        features.forEach( (name,type) -> create(name,type,category));
    }
```

myDTOs:

```java
@Data
public class CategoryDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private MainCategoryDTO mainCategory;
    private Set<FeatureDTO> features;
}

@Data
public class FeatureDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private FeatureType type;
}

@Data
public class MainCategoryDTO {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

**EDIT 1** :

i've added a method on my categoryService that sets the category features.

```java
    @Override
    public Category addFeatures(Category category, List<Feature> features) {
        category.setFeatures(features);
        return categoryRepository.save(category);
    }
```

and on my controller, i added the commented line so i can associate features to the category

```java
    @PostMapping("/sub")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_admin')")
    public HttpEntity<CategoryDTO> createSubCategory(@Valid @RequestBody CreateCategory createCategory)
    {
        Category category = categoryService.create(createCategory,mainCategoryService.one(createCategory.getMainCategory_id()));
        #category = categoryService.addFeatures(category,featureService.bulkCreate(createCategory.getFeatures(),category));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(modelMapper.map(category,CategoryDTO.class));
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set the Category's features collection? If it is empty when you pass it to save, it'll be empty when it returns.

Comment: Hi chris, i don't set it, i just create them in my createBulk method. do i need to query the category again so it fetches the features?

Comment: Yes, or just set both sides of your bi-directional relationship to save yourself an extra DB trip to fetch data you already have.

Comment: i'll show you what i did yesterday, it worked, but i don't know if it's the best way to do it

Comment: When you call f.setCategory(category), just also call category.getFeatures().add(f). Treat it like any other java class and you won't go wrong

Comment: i've updated my post, with the potential solution, it works but i think there's a lot of dependency between the two services.